# Prime Number Congruence Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, twin-primes

$6±1 = (5,7)$

**5 and 7 are twin primes**

$6 + 5 = 11$

$6 + 7 = 13$

**11 and 13 are twin primes**

$ 6 × 5 = 30 $

$ 6 × 7 = 42 $

**30 and 42 are adjacent to the twin primes (29. 31) and (41, 43)**

*Is there any other **multiple of 6** that is between twin primes (5,7),  produces this same pattern of primes in the sums (11, 13) and primes adjacent to its products (29. 31) and (41, 43)?* If so, how often does it occur?

Disclaimer: I don't know the mathematics necessary to figure it out on my own. I'm asking out of innocent curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two numbers that fit your requirements exactly - 6 and 109505970 - but if we loosen them a bit then we get an interesting sequence! The numbers we're trying to find need to satisfy the following conditions. If $n$ fits the pattern, then:

- $n+(n-1)$ is prime
- $n+(n+1)$ is prime
- $n(n-1) - 1$ is prime
- $n(n-1) + 1$ is prime
- $n(n+1) - 1$ is prime
- $n(n+1) + 1$ is prime

Below 10 million, there are 25 numbers that fit this pattern:
$3$, $6$, $21$, $1365$, $86604$, $185535$, $411501$, $759759$, $833799$, $1192290$, $1297815$, $2092719$, $2130324$, $2876160$, $3469311$, $3515799$, $5268606$, $5335959$, $7279791$, $7544901$, $7749435$, $7787661$, $7994085$, $8067501$, and $9954141$. This sequence ignores the "multiple of 6" condition and the "$n-1$ and $n+1$ have to be twin primes" condition.

If you add the condition that $n-1$ and $n+1$ also have to be prime, then the only numbers that I've found that satisfy this condition are $6$ and $109505970$, and $109505970$ is actually a multiple of 6!

Comment: According to the other comment which included my extra edit of 5 and 7 as primes, there are no such occurences, without that condition we get your result, correct?

Comment: Also, are you using a program to generate this?

Comment: His proof is wrong - 109505970 is a counter-example. I wrote a short program to do this in mathematica :)

Comment: The difference is in how the conditions are interpreted. This one looks for a number $n$ ($n=6$ in the example) such that $n\pm 1$, $2n\pm 1$, and $n(n\pm1)\pm1$ are primes. The other looks for a number such that $n\pm 1$, $(n+6)\pm 1$, and $6(n\pm 1)\pm 1$ are prime - in other words, it takes the usage of $6$ as a constant literal rather than as the 'seed value'.

Comment: It's no surprise that $1095605970$ is a multiple of 6, BTW; otherwise one of $n\pm 1$ will be divisible by either 2 or 3.

Comment: The only reason I made multiple of 6 a requirement was because all primes are adjacent to multiples of 6 except for 2 and 3

Comment: @JorgePerez Thanks for your help! I just realized that the sum of (5,7),(11,13),(29,31), and (41,43) equals 180 which is between the twin primes (179,181). Could you add this condition to Mathematica and see if you get any matches?